# How long does it take for nitric oxide to turn into dinitrogen and dioxygen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, decomposition

I'm new to chemistry and am studying nitric oxide as a combustion accelerant. Nitric oxide is said to be a free radical.

People say that nitric oxide, by itself, is pretty stable. But I saw that $$\ce{2NO -> N2 + O2}$$ so in a room of nitric oxide, will it decompose to nitrogen and oxygen?

Answer (score 11):

Theoretically, it will decompose, but the reaction is rather slow, on a human timescale. One experiment ran for almost forty *years* ([*J. Phys. Chem.* **1958,** *62* (3), 360–361](https://doi.org/10.1021/j150561a030)), from 1918 to 1957, without noticeable decomposition.

That said, in aqueous solutions it breaks down more rapidly. *In vivo*, the [half-life is a few *seconds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_oxide).

It is amazing to me that a free radical is so stable!

Comment: Then again, the decomposition pathway in vivo is **not** the one that leads to O2 and N2.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, true, and its physiological reaction (as opposed to decomposition) has engendered a large pharmaceutical market, which is still rising.